# Show/Hide div based on matched json data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to load all data from JSON file and I show matched data if `data[i]['brand_id'] == modelId`

```
<script>
    function loadModel(modelId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/api/model.json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    if (data[i]['brand_id'] == modelId) {
                        $('#item-brand-list').append('<option data-brand-id="' + modelId + '" value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</li>');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This function will be execute on this snippet:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.SelectOption', function () {
        var val = $(this).attr('data-val');
        loadModel(val); // here
    });
</script>
```

For example if any data (from JSON) equal by given `modelId` it append matched data into `select option` but I want to hide `select-ads-brand` if there is no match.

I tried:

```
<script>
    if (data[i]['brand_id'] == modelId) {
        $('#select-ads-brand').show();
        $('#item-brand-list').append('<option data-brand-id="' + modelId + '" value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</li>');
    } else {
        $('#select-ads-brand').hide();
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="select-ads-brand">
    <select id="item-brand-list">
        <option>-- Select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But no success, I think it's bad logic to show hide that `div`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try this for showing: $('#select-ads-brand').css('display', 'block') and this for hiding: $('#select-ads-brand').css('display', 'none');

Comment: @rohankangale `.show()` and `.hide()` do same thing.

Comment: Make the complete flow in a plnk with a fake json req  (timeout) and we'll fix it for u

Comment: You can't use show/hide function's for div. You have to make use of "display" property.

Comment: Who said that @rohankangale?

Comment: Issue is that you are looping through the data, so it might be hiding the element at first but at last iteration again showing it back as if condition passed.

Comment: yes, exactly the problem is. @CodeNewbie

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
function loadModel(modelId) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/api/model.json',
    success: function(data) {
      var foundMatch = false;
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        if (data[i]['brand_id'] == modelId) {
          $("#select-ads-brand").show(); // if match found show the div
          $('#item-brand-list').append('<option data-brand-id="' + modelId + '" value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]['name'] + '</li>');
          foundMatch = true; // set variable to true on success of match
        }
      });
      // if no match found simply hide the div
      if(!foundMatch) $("#select-ads-brand").hide();


    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just make use of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function and do check like this

```
const filtereddata = data.filter(ele => ele['brand_id']==modelId);
if(filtereddata.length > 0)
{
  //add filtered data
  $.each(filtereddata, function (i, v) {
                    $('#item-brand-list').append('<option data-brand-id="' + 
                     modelId + '" value="' + data[i]['id'] + '">' + data[i]
                      ['name'] + '</li>');

            });
  //show
   $('#select-ads-brand').show();
}
else 
{
  //hide
   $('#select-ads-brand').hide();
}
```